# Variable scope in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope

I just started using nodeJS and I am having some difficulties understanding the variable scope and referencing. For example in the code below, variable a will change/be overwritten even though the slice was made to variable b. My question is, how could I copy variable a into variable b without referencing it/overwriting variable a.

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var b = a;
b.splice(3,1);

console.log(a)    //will display ['a', 'b', 'c'] instead of ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying array by value in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761565/a-strange-thing-with-js-variables/15761907#15761907 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557654/pointer-behavior-between-objects/14557727#14557727 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a library like Amit suggested, this can be done natively and without installing a huge library...

Using `.slice()` with no arguments

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var b = a.slice();
b.splice(3,1);

console.log(a);
```

When you set `b = a`, you are NOT creating a new array, you are only telling `b` to hold a reference to `a`. So `a` and `b` are actually referencing the same location in memory. `.slice` works by returning a entire new array.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

b = a.slice(0);

or you could use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

b = [].slice(0);

for object there is also the [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method for objects.

and the [clone](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) method in underscore library

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you're looking for is know as deep clone or deep copy.

There are several ways to do this, for example you could use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep):

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var b = _.cloneDeep(a);
```

Comment: Yeahiii! -1 spree!!! Best when done without a comment

Comment: You're answer is overkill... why have him download, install and use lodash, when this can simply be done with native Javascript. `_.cloneDeep` is meant for objects, which are a little trickier to clone.

Comment: @ArianFaurtosh - The question is about general variables. The question was closed as dup referencing how to copy an array. It will not be long before the asking user find that an array copy doesn't work (`a = [{name: 'some name'}]; b = a.slice(); b[0].name = 'some other name'; console.log(a);`). My answer is an overkill for the sample code, not for the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but I found the answer to my problem. If anyone comes by this post and has the same problem, you can find the solution here [Nodejs: how to clone a object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089058/nodejs-how-to-clone-a-object#answer-12826757)